# Sqoop Import Job failed while extracting data from psql

Tags: import, mapreduce, gcloud, sqoop, broken-pipe

I am running a sqoop job on google cloud to import data from psql database after applying joins on 3 tables. However, sqoop job is getting failed with the below mentioned error, though it imports the data from the table within 15min but gets failed after running for 2hrs. I am able to extract other tables easily.

> Data Size: 13GB
>
> Query: gcloud compute ssh $INSTANCE_NAME --project=$PROJECT_ID
>   --service-account=$ACCOUNT --command="""$SQOOP_HOME/bin/sqoop-import -D mapreduce.output.basename='$TABLE_EXPORT' --connect jdbc:$JDBC://$HOST_NAME:$PORT/$DATABASE --username $USERNAME
>   --password '$PASSWORD' --target-dir $BUCKET_STORAGE -m $NUM_WORKERS --split-by $SPLIT_BY --query '$QUERY \$CONDITIONS ' --map-column-java $MAPPING_COLUMNS --fields-terminated-by '|' --null-string '' """
>   --zone=$ZONE 2>&1
>
> Error:
>
> 20/06/12 22:14:36 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
>
> 20/06/12 22:14:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
>
> 20/06/12 22:14:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 75% reduce 0%
>
> packet_write_wait: Connection to XX.XX.XXX.XXX port XX: Broken pipe
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code
>   [255].
>
> Command exited with return code 1

Answer (score 2):

The `packet_write_wait: Connection to XX.XX.XXX.XXX port XX: Broken pipe` error is usually an indication that the connection was ended because it has been idle for a while, which would make sense considering your command fails after 2 hours.

To remedy that, it was recommended in [another Stack post](https://superuser.com/a/1481260) to maintain the connection by configuring [ServerAliveInternal](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#ServerAliveInterval) and [ServerAliveCountMax](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#ServerAliveCountMax) and I recomemend that you read what they are used for.

Essentially, ServerAliveInternal set a time value that when reached, will have ssh send a message to request a message from the server, while ServerAliveCountMax sets the number of ServerAliveInternal messages that can be sent without receiving a resopnse back from the server before terminating the connection.

You would need to configure this in your client's ~/.ssh/config file, and you can check [this Stack post for reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/354245) or this [thread with the same issue](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/why-am-i-getting-packet_write_wait-connection-to-xxx-xx-xx-xxx-port-22-broken-pipe).

Comment: But ideally sqoop job should get exited once it extracts the data i.e. after 15 minutes